# Errors in class definition using data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm writing a class definition to accomplish the following tasks:

**1) Constructor**: accepts a filename of a .csv file as an argument, creates a data frame from the information in the file and stores this permanently in the object, sets column names for the data frame, sets the index to the individual's name. The internal data frame is a private attribute - do not change this.

**2) __in_frame**: private method which checks if a contact exists in the data frame, based on the name (You do not need to modify this, but you may need to use it in other methods)

**3) get_contact_info**: accepts a name as an argument, returns a list with the phone number and email for that contact, you must consider the case where the user requests a contact that doesn't exist

**4) get_phone**: accepts a name as an argument, returns the phone number for that contact, you must consider the case where the user requests a contact that doesn't exist

**5) get_email**: accepts a name as an argument, returns the email for that contact, you must consider the case where the user requests a contact that doesn't exist

**6) get_all_phones**: takes no arguments, returns the Series containing all of the phone numbers in the data set

**7) get_all_emails**: takes no arguments, returns the Series containing all of the emails in the data set

**8) add_change_contact**: takes a name, phone, and email as arguments, should add the contact to the data frame if it is not already there, otherwise should modify the existing contact

**9) delete_contact**: accepts  a name as an argument and deletes the contact from the data frame, you must consider the case where the user requests a contact that doesn't exist

**10) __str__**: return a string representation of the internal data frame

Here's my following code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Contact_Frame:

 def __init__(self, filename):
  self.__frame = pd.read_csv(filename)
  self.__frame.columns = ['Name','Phone','Email']
  self.__frame.set_index('Name')

 def __in_frame(self, name): 
   return name in self.__frame.index 

 def get_contact_info(self, name):
    if(__in_frame(name)):
      return self.__frame[name]

 def get_phone(self, name):
   if(__in_frame(name)):
     return self.__frame[name:'Phone']

 def get_email(self, name):
     return self.__frame[name:'Email']

 def get_all_phones(self):
     return self.__frame('Phone')

 def get_all_emails(self):
   return self.__frame('Email')

 def add__change_contact(self, name, phone, email):
   self.fame[name] = [phone, email]

 def delete_contact(self, name):
   if(__in_frame(name)):
     self.__frame.drop(name)

 def __str__(self):
    print (self.__frame)
```

When I run these I get several errors, what algorithmic/syntax errors are present in my code that stop my functions from running?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access class variables and functions from within that class, you must use self.

For example in delete_contact you have:

```
if(__in_frame(name)):
```

__in_frame is not defined within the functional scope. Replace this with

```
if(self.__in_frame(name)):
```